# ascii characters in a string-How to remove them

Tags: python, string, cryptography, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to encipher a text and I have the following problem:

I have a huge string (about 500+ pages concatenated together) which includes characters of the following form:

```
÷ΆώϋⁿΪⁿ÷ό±όⁿΈϊ÷ωΪⁿάⁿ÷ώ÷Ύ≤÷ώ
```

I need to remove these characters from my string, only I do not know how.
Assuming this big string is called `data`.
I am trying the following:

```
for i in data:
   if i not in string.ascii_letters and i not in n and i not in string.punctuation and i !=' ':
      data.replace(i,"")
```

However, it does not work, since after that I use the following command:

```
q=''
for i in data:
    if i not in string.ascii_letters and i not in n and i not in string.punctuation and i !=' ':
        q=q+i
print q
```

and `÷ΆώϋⁿΪⁿ÷ό±όⁿΈϊ÷ωΪⁿάⁿ÷ώ÷Ύ≤÷ώ` is printed once again.

Comment: Are you trying to remove some characters from an ciphertext?

Comment: Just an offtopic suggestion; use `if letter not in (string.ascii_letters, string.punctuation, ' ')` instead. This is _not_ your actual problem; Kevin below describes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  data.replace(i,"")
```

`replace` doesn't modify `data`, it creates a new string instance and returns it. Try assigning the result back to `data`:

```
  data = data.replace(i,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code that will remove non-ascii:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
data = 'poqwe÷ΆώϋⁿΪⁿbar÷ό±όⁿΈϊfoo÷ωΪⁿάⁿ÷ώ÷Ύ≤÷ώ42'
def remove_non_ascii(data):
    return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else '' for i in data])
data = remove_non_ascii(data)
print data
```

With simple for loop it would look like:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
data = 'poqwe÷ΆώϋⁿΪⁿbar÷ό±όⁿΈϊfoo÷ωΪⁿάⁿ÷ώ÷Ύ≤÷ώ42'
def remove_non_ascii(data):
    foo = ''
    for i in data:
        if (ord(i) < 128):
            foo += i
        else:
            foo += '' # whatever you wanna put instead of non-ascii
    return foo 
data = remove_non_ascii(data)
print data
```